# search engine in laravel not working + functions

Tags: php, html, laravel

so this is my controller :

```
        class PostsController extends BaseController
    {
        public function postSearch()
        {
        $q = Input::get('username');

        $posts = DB::table('users')->whereRaw(
            "MATCH(username) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
            array($q)
        )->get();

        return View::make('posts.index', compact('posts'));

    }


}
```

and my route :

```
Route::get('posts/index', function()
{
    return View::make('posts/index');
});


Route::post(
    ''posts/index',
    array(
        'as' => 'posts.index',
        'uses' => 'PostsController@postSearch'
    )


);
```

and my html :

```
<div class="search">
    {{ Form::model(null, array('route' => array('posts.index'))) }}
    {{ Form::text('username', null, array( 'placeholder' => 'Search query...' )) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Search') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}


</div>
```

the problem is it give me error :

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException
```

so i wasnt for users to be able to search in the index page and give them the result in the diffident page in a table 
how can i make the result appear and what is this error ?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything fine,but  in route file your class is named as `PostsController` but the actual controller class name is `postController` this is why it says `PostsController` not found.

**Route:**

```
Route::get('posts/index', function()
{
    return View::make('posts/index');
});

Route::post('posts/index', array('as' => 'posts.index','uses' => 'PostsController@postSearch'));
```

**Controller**

```
class PostsController extends BaseController
{
    public function postSearch()
    {
        $q = Input::get('username');

        $posts = DB::table('users')->whereRaw(
            "MATCH(username) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE)",
            array($q)
        )->get();

        return View::make('posts.index', compact('posts'));

    }
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="search">
    {{ Form::open(array('route' => 'post.index', 'method' => 'POST', 'role' => 'search')) }}
    {{ Form::text('username',null, array( 'placeholder' => 'Search query...' )) }}
    {{ Form::submit('Search') }}
    {{ Form::close() }}
</div>

@if(isset($posts))

@foreach($posts as $post)

{{$post->id}}

@endforeach

@endif
```

Comment: i ve changed my {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) }}
to what you said but it gave me same error :(

Comment: did you change your controller class name? `postController` to `PostsController` ?

Comment: Well this is now a complete a different story. You have to change your database table now. Something like this: `ALTER TABLE yourtablename ADD FULLTEXT fulltext_index(username)`.

Comment: yupe tanx that helped and cleared that error but i get this now :
View [posts.index] not found.

Comment: ahhh, can you show your views folder directory structure? It must be like this  Views -> posts -> index.blade.php then it will not give this error.

Comment: lol sorry if i giving u a haeadache :D it was in the view's and its working now tnx a mil
but now it doesn't giving me any result when i put and text to it and hit submit it just refreshes the page

Comment: `var_dump($posts);` and see the results?

Comment: Please use the above code and let me know if there is any error.

Comment: yes copied but same : NotFoundHttpException error , this error should be gone by adding any instead of post or get alright ? but it wont :(